# Oracle query showing error "not a GROUP BY expression"

Tags: sql, database, oracle

Hello I have made a query to get employee first in and last out time for a date range for this I used max and min function to get first in and last out time here is my query

```
     select 
     fullname,
     "IN",
     out
     from
     (
            select
            fullname,direction,
            employment.employeeid,NATIONALID,departmentname,designation.designationname,
            min(case when direction = 'IN' then to_date(to_char(((TO_DATE('19700101','yyyymmdd') + (tstamp/24/60/60) + 6/24)), 'dd-mm-yyyy hh12:mi:ss PM'), 'dd-mm-yyyy hh:mi:ss pm') end) "IN",
            max(case when direction = 'OUT' then to_date(to_char(((TO_DATE('19700101','yyyymmdd') + (tstamp/24/60/60) + 6/24)), 'dd-mm-yyyy hh12:mi:ss PM'), 'dd-mm-yyyy hh:mi:ss pm') end) out
            from eofficeuat.entrylog_cpa
            join eofficeuat.employee on entrylog_cpa.hrrecordid=employee.hrrecordid
            join eofficeuat.employment on employee.hrrecordid=employment.hrrecordid
            join eofficeuat.designation on employment.designationid=designation.designationid
            join eofficeuat.department on employment.departmentid=department.departmentid
            where department.departmentname = 'SECURITY'
            and tstamp >= 1567274400 and tstamp < 1569862800 
            and eofficeuat.employment.employeeid='022013'
            group by eofficeuat.employment.employeeid
            order by tstamp asc

      )
```

but I am getting this error

```
      ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression
```

please tell me how can i fix this.

Comment: You typically GROUP BY the same columns as you SELECT, except those who are arguments to set functions.

Comment: group by employment.employeeid, fullname, direction, NATIONALID, departmentname, designation.designationname

Comment: @ϻᴇᴛᴀʟ still I am getting this error

Comment: you used table name eofficeuat in group by. Remove it. Else just paste this after group by  employment.employeeid,NATIONALID,departmentname,designation.designationname

Comment: @sandy v I not see any dot after table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Columns that aren't aggregated should be part of the `GROUP BY` clause, which means this:

```
    GROUP BY fullname,
             direction,
             employment.employeeid,
             NATIONALID,
             departmentname,
             designation.designationname
```

Also, you'd probably want to move `ORDER BY` out of the inline view.

Comment: I am still getting this error for with group by you mentioned

Comment: You shouldn't have. Could you, please, copy/paste your SQL*Plus session so that we'd see what Oracle says?

Comment: ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression
00979. 00000 -  "not a GROUP BY expression"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 26 Column: 26

Comment: I know how that error looks like. I want to see what causes it. It says "line 26", but your code doesn't have 26 lines.

Comment: order by tstamp asc

Comment: TSTAMP isn't among columns that are selected. If you want to use it in ORDER BY, you'll have to include it into GROUP BY as well. Or - remove the ORDER BY clause completely if including it into GROUP BY affects result you got (looking at the query, yes - it will affect it).

Answer (score 0):

include non-aggregated columns in group by clause 
also you should include the case completely in group by clause.
try below query

```
select 
     fullname,
     "IN",
     out
     from
     (
            select
            fullname,direction,
            employment.employeeid,NATIONALID,departmentname,designation.designationname,
            min(case when direction = 'IN' then to_date(to_char(((TO_DATE('19700101','yyyymmdd') + (tstamp/24/60/60) + 6/24)), 'dd-mm-yyyy hh12:mi:ss PM'), 'dd-mm-yyyy hh:mi:ss pm') end) "IN",
            max(case when direction = 'OUT' then to_date(to_char(((TO_DATE('19700101','yyyymmdd') + (tstamp/24/60/60) + 6/24)), 'dd-mm-yyyy hh12:mi:ss PM'), 'dd-mm-yyyy hh:mi:ss pm') end) out
            from eofficeuat.entrylog_cpa
            join eofficeuat.employee on entrylog_cpa.hrrecordid=employee.hrrecordid
            join eofficeuat.employment on employee.hrrecordid=employment.hrrecordid
            join eofficeuat.designation on employment.designationid=designation.designationid
            join eofficeuat.department on employment.departmentid=department.departmentid
            where department.departmentname = 'SECURITY'
            and tstamp >= 1567274400 and tstamp < 1569862800 
            and eofficeuat.employment.employeeid='022013'
            group by 
            fullname,
            direction,
            employment.employeeid,
            NATIONALID,
            departmentname,
            designation.designationname,
            case when direction = 'IN' then to_date(to_char(((TO_DATE('19700101','yyyymmdd') + (tstamp/24/60/60) + 6/24)), 'dd-mm-yyyy hh12:mi:ss PM'), 'dd-mm-yyyy hh:mi:ss pm') end,
            case when direction = 'OUT' then to_date(to_char(((TO_DATE('19700101','yyyymmdd') + (tstamp/24/60/60) + 6/24)), 'dd-mm-yyyy hh12:mi:ss PM'), 'dd-mm-yyyy hh:mi:ss pm') end
            order by tstamp asc

      )
```